# Is there an equivalent of Promise.all in mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I looked in the docs but couldnt find it.
looking for something like the following

```
let promise = new Promise(someExecutor);
let promise2 = new Promise(executor2);
Promise.all([promise,promise2]).then(someFunc);

let userQ = User.find(someId);
let postQ = Post.find(someIdforPost);
//Mongoose.Query.all([userQ, postQ])??
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongoose find function returns a promise anyways. So you can handle this similar to the 1st example in your code.

Just use `Promise.all([userQ, postQ]).then(someFunc)`

Comment: the doc states that the find function returns a query object and is different from Promise, does it still work with Promise.all?

Comment: They use https://www.npmjs.com/package/co i think which have a lot of Promise functionality. afaik Promise.all works properly with find queries in mongoose.